# What is the top movie genre using the average rank per movie genre as the metric?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, join, mysql-workbench

Currently, I am teaching my self SQL and i came across a very interesting question which says:
***Based ratings with 10,000 or more votes, what is the top movie genre using the
average rank per movie genre as the metric?***
***(Note: where a higher value for rank is considered a better movie)***

So here are the tables: **rating**

```
+---------+------+--------+--------------+
| movieid | rank | votes  | distribution |
+---------+------+--------+--------------+
| 1672052 | 7.8  |   8111 | 0000001222   |
| 1672111 | 5.3  |  32183 | 0001221000   |
| 1672580 | 4.4  |   1894 | 0011110000   |
| 1672716 | 7.0  |   1255 | 0000001212   |
| 1673647 | 6.5  |    128 | 0000111211   |
| 1673658 | 3.9  |     20 | 22101.10.1   |
| 1673848 | 7.0  | 137748 | 0000012211   |
| 1674388 | 5.5  |  47380 | 0001221000   |
```

**Table: movie_directores**

```
+---------+------------+-------------+
| movieid | directorid | genre       |
+---------+------------+-------------+
| 1672052 |      22397 | Drama       |
| 1672111 |      54934 | Action      |
| 1672580 |     297253 | Comedy      |
| 1672716 |     188926 | Drama       |
| 1672946 |     188940 | Action      |
| 1673647 |     302682 | Drama       |
| 1673658 |     155385 | Comedy      |
| 1673848 |     133605 | Comedy      |
| 1674388 |     115990 | Adventure   |
| 1674737 |     164962 | Drama       |
| 1677011 |     116812 | Comedy      |
| 1677258 |      99002 | Comedy      |
| 1677346 |      22912 | Biography   |
```

what I want is: Based on ratings with 10,000 or more votes, I want to know what is the  top movie genre using the average rank per movie genre as the metric

what I did so far is this:

```
SELECT movieid
FROM rating m
JOIN (
SELECT movieid, COUNT(movieid) 
FROM rating) 
ON m.movieid = r.movieid
count(*)>=10000
```

not sure if the logic is correct . any help?

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
select md.genre, avg(r.rank) avg_rank
from movies_directores md
inner join rating r on r.movieid = md.movieid
where r.votes > 10000
group by md.genre
order by avg(r.rank) desc
limit 1
```